# Bundle or Grouped Product set with default quantity

Tags: configurable-product, bundled-product, inventory, grouped-products

I have simple products for sale in my store that I want to group together.
We want to create a bundle or grouped listing that has a fixed quantity other of the default (1), thus creating a package deal that can't be altered by the customer and comes as a fixed price.
Is there a way to do this? I've tried making all configurable, bundle and grouped but they all give the option of the customer to have to checkbox something.

Comment: i'm also looking for same now. how you done this